# How to use html input data in jinja {{url_for()}}

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask to render templates in html using jinja.

I have made a form in html

```
<form class="container-fluid">
    <div class="input-group col-4">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">?img=</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Image URL" aria-label="Image URL"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="img_arg_input">
    </div>
    <a href="{{ url_for('home', img='') }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        Submit
    </a>
</form>
```

I'm running this on Flask on a local server `http://127.0.0.1:5000`

In the url_for I am using `img=''` for giving argument to the link. Currently it loads `http://127.0.0.1:5000/home?img=` because I'm giving empty string. **I want to replace that empty string with whatever I write in the input html tag.**

My home function in flask application looks like this:

```
@application.route('/home')
def home():
    home_data = {
        'message': 'Home'
    }
    img_file = request.args.get("img")
    if img_file:
        home_data['img_file'] = img_file
    return render_template('home.html', home_data = home_data)
```

Here I'm calling request.args.get and using that value which is seperate.

**My main concern is how to use whatever I write in my input html tag in the url_for as an argument**

Or am I looking at this problem for a wrong perspective, any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I have a follow up question, what if in future I want to create something like this

```
@application.route('/data/<name>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def data(name):
    ...
```

How will I go about using url_for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `request.args.get` and transport the parameters within the URL, you need a form with the GET `method`, which corresponds to the default value.
This form can be submitted via either an `input` or a `button` of type `submit`, not via an anchor.

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="input-id">My Input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="input-name" id="input-id" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The name of the input field corresponds to the key with which the value can be queried on the server side.

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    my_input = request.args.get('input-name')
    print(my_input)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Using `url_for` is only necessary if the form is to be sent to a different endpoint than the template comes from. In this case, the `action` parameter of the form must be assigned.

If you want to upload an image, it is advisable to take a look at the documentation under ["Uploading Files"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/#uploading-files).

You can find the use of variable rules together with `url_for` in the sections ["Variable Rules"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) and ["URL Building"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#url-building).